# How do I get the mouse position in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

This code works in Google Chrome and IE but not in FireFox.

```
function drawChildren(names) {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");       
    var ctxcolor = "#000000";

    if(listeners < 1){
        c.addEventListener("click", getPosition, false);
        listeners = 1;
    } // At the click function "getPosition" is executed
}

function getPosition(event) {

    if ( event.offsetX == null ) { // Firefox
        clickedX = event.layerX;
        clickedY = event.layerY;
    } else {                       // Other browsers
        clickedX = event.offsetX;
        clickedY = event.offsetY;
    }

    checkCoordinates(clickedX, clickedY);  
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an explanation

Comment: provide the error thrown by FF please.

Comment: I solved the problem, but I'm still not clear how the offset and layer really works.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljcpdudj.php
http://help.dottoro.com/ljjqvtaf.php

Maybe I dont understand what is the element that fires the event. In the code above: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
Is it canvas element that fires the event? I would be happy if someone explained it to me in detail.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question posted in the above comment, your `function getPosition()` will be called whenever `myCanvas` is clicked. (Because your code says `c.addEventListener("click", getPosition, false);`)

Using your mouse position detection code, I'm not sure how the offset and layering works either, but if you use the following code, then I know you will always get x and y coordinates starting from the edge of the browser, rather than starting in any elements of your site:

```
if(evt.pageX){
    var xPos = evt.pageX;
    var yPos = evt.pageY;
}else if(evt.clientX){
    var xPos = evt.clientX + ((document.documentElement.scrollLeft) ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    var yPos = evt.clientY + ((document.documentElement.scrollTop) ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

Your code may do the same thing as this, but I just wanted to provide what works for me also :)